# Laravel Excel export

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

necesito generar un excel con datos de 2 tablas relacionadas, como creo el join para generar el excel, segun la doc es con Query pero no se donde poner mi sentencia eloquent o sql

```
public function query()
{
    return PersonasNaturales::query();
}
```

CONTROLADOR

```
public function exportPersonasNatural(){
    // $excel=new PersonaJuridicaExport;
    return (new PersonaNaturalesExport)->download('Personas_Naturales.xlsx');

}
```

MODELO

```
class PersonasNaturales extends Model
private $fillable=[...]
public function persona()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Persona::class);
}
```

Comment: Para eso Eloquent tiene sus relaciones, investiga un poco al respecto además para poderte ayudar necesitas mostrar que llevas hecho amigo; pues sin tu código nosotros tampoco sabemos cómo ayudar

Comment: De paso lee [ask] , edita y mejora tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes dentro de la función query de la clase que implemente FromQuery escribir lo siguiente por ejemplo:

```
public function query()
{
   //Con esto devolverias solo los campos que necesitas de la tabla persona asi no los exportas todos, debes ver cuales son los que quieres exportar a excel de esa tabla
   return PersonasNaturales::with('persona:id,name,edad');
}

//Si quieres limitar los exportados de la tabla PersonasNaturales puedes hacerlos con
   return PersonasNaturales::select(['campo1, 'campo2', 'campo3'])->width('....')
//Los ... es para representar que pudes hacer lo mismo que en la explicación de arriba.
```

Con eso devolverias el queryBuilder que es lo que ella espera, para construir el excel si quieres personificarlo mas puedes agregar alguna que otra consulta por ejemplo si quisieses las que estuvieran activas y solo las de sexo femenino y ordenarlas por el name ascendentemente por ejemplo pudieras hacer algo como esto, asumiendo que esos campos existieran en tu tabla claro esta, es solo como ejemplo ilustrativo:

```
public function query()
{
   return PersonasNaturales::with('persona')
           ->where('active', 1)
           ->where('gender', 'F')
           ->orderBy('name');
}
```

Se pueden hacer muchas mas cosas, como por ejemplo injectar el repositorio y llamar a la función que deseas para evitar hacer la consulta en este lado, pero bueno hasme saber si entendistes y si te funcionó.